# Pandas: inverse of value_counts function

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

What's a quick way to produce the inverse output of the value_counts function?

For example, if I have the following series:

```
1      24
2       2
3       1
4       2
5       3
6      12
7      21
8     204
9     400
10     71
11    160
Name: foo, dtype: float64
```

How can I concisely produce the following array?

```
numpy.array([1, 1, 1, ... , 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, ... ])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html). If your Series is named `s`, it's possible to write:

```
np.repeat(s.index.values, s.values)
```

Here `s.index.values` are the values to repeat, and `s.values` specifies the number of times that each value should be repeated. The output is a 1D array.

Comment: Nice! In this case, since the series was dtype float, I had to use `np.repeat(s.index.values, s.values.astype('int'))`.